# Можно ли в application.properties создать переменную , которую можно вызвать в Logback.xml

Tags: spring-boot, logback

Проект на Springboot. В качестве системы логгирования используется logback.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds" >

<!-- Переопределим стандартные настройки системы логгирования.-->
    <include resource="defaults-spring.xml"/>


    <!--Профиль по умолчанию, вывод сообщений только в консоль.-->
    <springProfile name="default">

        <include resource="console-appender-spring.xml"/>

        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>

    </springProfile>


    <!--Профиль по умолчанию, вывод сообщений только в консоль.-->
    <springProfile name="production">

        <!--  настройки аппендеров для текущего профиля-->
        <include resource="logback-appender-production-spring.xml"/>

        <!--  Указываем для пакета, какой уровень логгирования, будет обрабатываться
               текущим профилем.-->
        <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>

        <logger name="org.springframework.data" level="DEBUG">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </logger>


        <!--  Указываем для пакета, какой уровень логгирования, будет обрабатываться
          текущим профилем.-->
        <logger name="DOMAIN" level="ERROR">

            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>

        </logger>

        <logger name="DOMAIN" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        </logger>

        <!--  Указываем для пакета, какой уровень логгирования, будет обрабатываться
        текущим профилем.-->
        <logger name="CONTROLLER" level="INFO">

            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>

        </logger>



    </springProfile>


</configuration>
```

Вызывается аппендер для rollover.

```xml
     <!--  настройки аппендеров для текущего профиля-->
        <include resource="logback-appender-production-spring.xml"/>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<included>

    <include resource="defaults-spring.xml"/>

    <property name="ARCHIVE_DIR" value="logs"/>

  <property name="FILE_LOG_NAME" value="${ARCHIVE_DIR}/mylogger.log"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

       <!-- <file>${FILE_LOG_NAME}</file>-->

        <file>${FILE_LOG_NAME}</file>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <!--  В данном случае, архивный каталог создается каждую 'минуту'.
             Здесь обрататите внимание на  `_mm` в имени архивной папки. Это означает, что архивная
              папка будет создаваться каждую минуту. Можно указать: mm, HH, MM, dd;
              %i - указвывает на порядковый номер архива, в текущем архивном каталоге. -->
            <fileNamePattern>${ARCHIVE_DIR}/archived_%d{dd-MM-yyyy_mm}/app.%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

            <!-- указывает на максимальный размер лог-файла, здесь размер 1KB
             Если размер превышается, тогда файл помещается в архив-->
            <maxFileSize>1KB</maxFileSize>

            <!-- Общее количество всех архивных файлов,
             если общий размер архивных файлов в текущем каталоге больше чем указано, то
             файлы удаляются из архивного каталога. Удаление начинается с тех, которые были
             самими ранними.
              -->
            <totalSizeCap>5KB</totalSizeCap>

            <!-- Указан период (в днях), в течении которого будет хранится архивный лог,
             по истечении данного срока, все файлы удаляются из текущего архивного каталога-->
            <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>


</included>
```

хотелось бы названия типа

```xml
<... value="..../mylogger.log"/>
```

вынести в application.properties, а затем вызывать оттуда в виде переменной ${FILE_LOG_NAME}...

Как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант Вы можете сделать так:

[обозначить](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48457902/8370915) в `application.properties` файле Ваш `logging.file`:

```
logging.file=.../mylogger.log
```

затем в `logback.xml` написать:

```
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

и [обратиться к нужному свойству](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40498588/8370915):

```
${logging.file}
```

Для получения более детальной информации, можете обратиться к [официальной документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-logback-for-logging-fileonly) и вспомогательным источникам с примерами:

> https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/
>   https://dzone.com/articles/configuring-logback-with-spring-boot